# Modify SQL query to filter results

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to modify the function below to `filter records` in the table that have column "type" equal to "hod"

```
 public function getHOD() {

        $query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `' . $this->table . 'WHERE type=hod`;');
        $query->execute();

        if ($query->rowCount() == 0) return null;

}
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to add WHERE type=hod into the query?

Answer (score 1):

Here are multiple things that you need to fix:

1. You added ` before table name, but not after
2. You need a space before `WHERE`
3. You need to add `'` around `hod`

If I did not miss anything your query should look like this:

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . $this->table . "` WHERE type='hod'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in quotes

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . $this->table . "` WHERE type='hod'");
```

Comment: It is returning the error: Array ( [0] => 42S02 [1] => 1146 [2] => Table 'db_name.table_name WHERE type='hod'' doesn't exist )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a space is missing in 'WHERE, which should say ' WHERE.
And hod, if it's a string should have quotes in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" .$this->table. "` WHERE type='hod'");
```

Comment: It is returning the error: Array ( [0] => 42S02 [1] => 1146 [2] => Table 'db_name.table_name WHERE type='hod'' doesn't exist )

Comment: plz print **$this->table** and check table name is correct or not @cpcdev

Comment: ok than try this **echo "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table . " WHERE type='hod'";**  or run in phpmyadmin @cpcdev